# How to install a Cisco valet connector without internet?

Tags: networking, internet, cisco

I installed Ubuntu to try it out. My computer doesn’t have internal internet card.

So I would like to use **Cisco valet connector**.

My question is how do I install it ?

- I can't open an exe file,
- I can't install wine because there is no internet.

Any other way?

Comment: Install your Cisco Valet Connector? This is a place for questions about Ubuntu.

Comment: What happens when you plug the valet in?

Comment: To install Wine without an internet connection, use a device that does have an internet connection to download the packages.

Comment: When i plug in cisco a file popups that contains the setup.exe and some other stuff. The problem is i cant install without wine compatibilty and i dont have internet connection to install wine

Comment: You need to read this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1808690

Comment: Idk how to/where to start, can you guys help me? Im a beginner

Comment: Yes, read that entire thread. The answer is in there

Comment: I got to work. My brain almkst exploded. Thanks for finding that forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Wine once you get an internet connection, copy and paste the following commands:

`sudo su`

Then type:

`add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa --y && apt-get update && apt-get install wine1.7 wine wine-gecko2.24 gnome-exe-thumbnailer --y`

That does everything automatically. Just paste the first command in, enter your password, and enter the big command. The big command adds a PPA that will keep Wine up to date with the latest development version.

Comment: I don't think the question here is how to get wine, and after switching to root you no longer need to use sudo in your "big command"

Comment: I know. I was just too lazy to change it. I'll fix it now anyway.